# Finding a specific computer from an IP address on a network

Tags: networking, ip, 3dsmax

I'm having trouble with my network at work.
We have a LOT of computers on our network and one of them is causing me problems.
I'm rendering from 3ds Max via Backburner and I can see that there is a another manager distributing jobs.
I can see the IP adress of the computer (198.162.1.61), I just don't know where it is or what it's called.

Is there any way to get a specefic computers information if I only know its IP address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consult the ARP table. Then you'll get the MAC address, this you can match with the vendor via:

http://www.adminsub.net/mac-address-finder

command:

```
arp -a
```

use the following command to see the name of the computer:

```
nbtstat –a <ipaddress>
```

if you are lucky, you can also gather information via scans (ex program: autoscan, nmap, ...)